# Is it possible to cast a retrieved Class object (via reflection) to an interface?

Tags: java, android, reflection

I have 3 projects in my workspace - A, B, and C which is an Android lib project.

1. A contains an Activity named `Atest`
2. B contains a class named `Btest` which implements interface `I`.
3. C contains the `I` interface.

Both A and B are installed on my Android device.
During `Atest` runtime, i'm executing the next code:

```
Context otherContext = createPackageContext("com.package.b",
                CONTEXT_INCLUDE_CODE | CONTEXT_IGNORE_SECURITY);
ClassLoader loader = otherContext.getClassLoader();
Class<?> btest = Class.forName("com.package.b.BTest", true, loader);
```

Now here is my question - is there any way to cast btest into `I` within `A` run context?

I've tried many obvious (and several not-so-obvious) tricks, and nothing worked for me. I can of-course explore btest's methods and interfaces, invoke its methods, etc.. but I simply can't cast it into `I`, although both A and B referring the exact same `I` interface in lib-project C.

Thanks in advance!

P.S.

Kindly note that I'm casting it into an interface, not into an object, so I guess different `ClassLoader` isn't the reason in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are doing all of this dynamic loading at run time there is no construction of a virtual method table and its associated vpointers. Therefore there no way for the runtime to dynamically dispatch calls to the interface methods to the appropriately loaded implementation. You have to use reflection.

Comment: So simple, so clear. Is there any escaping of accessing the object methods via "invoke"? I must access that object via reflection though...

Comment: 1) Virtual method tables are an implementation detail.  2) I'm pretty sure they would be constructed for dynamically loaded classes.  When the JVM notices that a new class has been loaded that violates previous assumptions, it triggers JIT recompilation.  3) In fact, from a certain perspective **all** Java classes are dynamically loaded, apart from (arguably) some bootstrap classes.

Answer (score 1):

I presume you are talking about casting an INSTANCE of `Btest` to the interface `I`.

- If both `Btest` and `I` are statically loaded, then `(I) bTestInstance` does the job.
- If `I` alone is statically loaded, then `(I) bTestInstance` also does the job ... provided that the classloader that loaded `Btest` hasn't load its own version of `I`.  (In that case, you will have two different `I` types, and the typecast will fail with a runtime exception.)
- If both `Btest` and `I` are dynamically loaded, and `Btest` implements `I`, then the following should work:

  ```
      Class<?> btestCls = Class.forName("com.package.b.Btest", true, loader);
      // This will work, because I has to be on the classpath of 'loader'
      // for the previous load to work ...
      Class<?> iCls = Class.forName("com.package.i.I", true, loader);

      Object btest = // create a Btest instance reflectively
      Object i = iCls.cast(btest);
  ```

  The problem of course is that since your code has dynamically loaded **both** `BTest` and `I`, there's no way to declare a variable whose static type is `BTest` or `I`.  And there is no way to write a type cast expression `(I) btest`.

The other possibility is that you were talking about casting the `Class` objects.  But that doesn't make any sense given that you have to use a wild-card as the type parameter for `Class`.

---

Just to reiterate, if `I` is statically linked into your code then you can do this:

```
Object btest = // create or retrieve the instance reflectively
I i = (I) btest;
```

If `I` is NOT statically linked into your code, then you (obviously) cannot declare `I i` in the above, or write `(I) btest`.  The Java language simply does not allow it.

You therefore have to use reflection for all manipulations of a `BTest` instance.  My understanding is that you want to avoid that.  Unfortunately, you can't.

---

The JLS simply doesn't provide any way to:

- declare a variable of a (compile time) unknown type,
- type cast to an unknown type, or
- invoke a method when you don't (at compile time) if the method exists.

The reason for these limitations<sup>1</sup> is deeper that vtables, etc.  (The **real** reason is that it is impossible to do static typing when the types are completely unknown at compile time.  Java is *designed* to be a statically type checked language at its core, and this kind of thing would go against that design principle.

---

<sup>1 - Those just an implementation details.  Java implementations use vtables because the JLS permits it, not the other way around.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

The interface `I` must be on the classpath (or otherwise loadable by the runtime), otherwise you're going to get a runtime exception. Refelection won't allow you to avoid this issue.

Comment: `A` is linked to `C`, so I guess that `I` is on the classpath.

Comment: Yes, if `C` is a usable class, this would mean `I` is loadable. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I want to refer to `Btest` as an `I`, and I can't. I can only refer it as Object or Class<?>/Class<Test> object, which means I won't be able to call its implemented interface methods directly but I can just use "invoke". Is it more clear now?

Comment: What happens if you import `I` and just cast `Btest` to an `I`? Do you get a compiler error?

Comment: Inside `B` process it is possible of-course; it is only failed while doing it inside `A` context.

Comment: If you want to cast something to `I` you need to have access to `I`. There is no way around this.

Comment: What do you ultimately attempt to accomplish?

Comment: I DO have access to `I` from both `A` and `B`, both projects are linked to the same lib-package, `C`, which contains `I`.

Comment: `Btest` is a *class*. You don't cast *classes*, you cast *objects*. You need a concrete instance of `Btest`

Comment: Of course i'm calling newInstance(), and yet - I can't cast that object to `I`